# C# created Excel graph - Should be ScatterLine but it is Line type on other computers

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, excel, excel-2010

I am having a problem making the Excel graph-type appear as a ScatterLine.  Oddly, after compiled, on my computer it appears as ScatterLine, but on everyone else's it appears as a Line type that has no X axis!

```
    private void showExcelXY_Open(ArrayList al)
    {
        ArrayList alX = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList alY = new ArrayList();
        alX.Clear();
        alY.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] val = al[i].ToString().Split('^');
            alX.Add(val[0]);
            alY.Add(val[1]);
        }

        xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        xla.Visible = true;
        Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;

        // Now create the chart.
        ChartObjects chartObjs = (ChartObjects)ws.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        ChartObject chartObj = chartObjs.Add(100, 20, 500, 300);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart xlChart = chartObj.Chart;

        //add some data from your datasource like a dataset or like below.
        ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Pressure";
        ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Compression";

        ws.Cells[2, 1] = alX[0];
        ws.Cells[2, 2] = alY[0];

        ws.Cells[3, 1] = alX[1];
        ws.Cells[3, 2] = alY[1];

        ws.Cells[4, 1] = alX[2];
        ws.Cells[4, 2] = alY[2];

        ws.Cells[5, 1] = alX[3];
        ws.Cells[5, 2] = alY[3];

        ws.Cells[6, 1] = alX[4];
        ws.Cells[6, 2] = alY[4];

        ws.Cells[7, 1] = alX[5];
        ws.Cells[7, 2] = alY[5];

        ws.Cells[8, 1] = alX[6];
        ws.Cells[8, 2] = alY[6];

        //set the source data and the chart type.
        Range chartRange = ws.get_Range("A2", "B8");
        xlChart.SetSourceData(chartRange, Type.Missing);
        xlChart.ChartType = XlChartType.xlXYScatterLines;

        // Customize axes:
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis xAxis = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis)xlChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlCategory, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        xAxis.HasMajorGridlines = true;
        xAxis.HasTitle = true;
        xAxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Above         Pressure (psi)          Below";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis yAxis = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis)xlChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
        yAxis.MajorTickMark = XlTickMark.xlTickMarkCross;
        yAxis.HasTitle = true;
        yAxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Compression (lbf)";

        // Add title:
        xlChart.HasTitle = true;
        xlChart.ChartTitle.Text = "XPak Performance Envelope" + '\n' + "(Open Top & Bottom)";

        // Remove legend:
        xlChart.HasLegend = false;
   }
```

The code clearly shows that it is setting the chart-type as:

```
xlChart.ChartType = XlChartType.xlXYScatterLines;
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the Excel versions the same on both computers? If they are, try recording macros to create a scatterline graph on both computers and see what the VBA is recorded as. That might tell you what the difference is.

Comment: Hey Sid, thanks for your suggestion.  That's a great idea!  The other computers are all running Excel 2010, including mine.  It is frustrating when it works on mine but when compiled doesn't on the the others. Oddly it still works fine on mine.  I'll report back when I find out what their VBA contain.  Thanks again! Bob

Comment: Sid, I just finished running macros on the other machines and they all created the same code which includes "ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers".  My macro looks exactly the same as the others, so no differences there.  Someone suggested changing the default chart on the other machines.  We looked and everyone's default is "xlLine".  I reset everyone's default to "xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers".  I re-ran the program on their machines and it worked properly.  But, everyone's default has to be changed!  This will work for me, but I don't know if this is the best solution.

Comment: I notice that there is a `Chart.SetDefaultChart()` method in Interop. I wonder if playing with that might yield some results? Perhaps set it before you begin creating your chart. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.chart.setdefaultchart(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: That would allow a change inside code which would be great!  I'm going to see what that can do.  Many thanks!!!  I'll reply back here with the results.

Comment: I inserted "chartPage.SetDefaultChart(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers);" into my code.  I went to another machine and reset the Excel default chart to "xlLine".  I had them run the program and see if it would create an Excel XYScatterLinesNoMarkers.  Unfortunately it didn't, it came in as an xlLIne type.  I had him do one more before closing and this one came in as the required "XYScatterLinesNoMarkers".  It apparently didn't respond to the first Excel chart but did on the second!

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps it needs to be set before you begin creating a chart (which might be tricky since it is a method on the chart object). You could try instantiating a chart object just to set the default chart type, then remove the reference and instantiate another one. Just a guess, but it might do the trick.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  Maybe when the program launches instantiate the chart object.  I'll reply back here asap.

Comment: I created a procedure to execute during Form_Load that executed Chart.SetDefaultChart()  I am hoping this has resolved the issue, but I'm going to reset a few back to "xlLine" and retry.

Comment: When Excel is set to xlLine as default my code won't work.  But if it is set to xlXYScatterLinesNoMarker it will.  I am having to set everyones Excel accordingly.

Comment: If someone's code changed my default chart type without telling me, and without changing it back, I'd probably be upset. Make a note of the current default, change to what you need, then change back.

Comment: I don't know why xlChart.ChartType = XlChartType.xlXYScatterLines; doesn't give you the chart type you expect. Sometimes running a command twice makes it work (something like Bob T noted above). Insert the line before setting the source data as well as after, see if that helps.

Comment: "I don't know why xlChart.ChartType = XlChartType.xlXYScatterLines; doesn't give you the chart type you expect." Jon, me either. Trying the command twice is a good idea, I'll try that and report back.