# How to change the default chart type for add-in, workbook or sheet (not for chart)?

Tags: c#, excel, charts

Excel add-in generates error creating chart if user have previously set an MS Excel default chart belonging to one of the following chart groups: Stock charts and Surface charts. For the last the error is: "The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type"

I use ChartObjects and can't add an empty chart without an error and so it's impossible to set a chart type.
The problem is that Excel generates errors for that charts if you try to make it without properly data selection. Try youself by setting one of these types as default and pressing Alt+F1.

Does anybody know how to change the default chart type for add-in, workbook or sheet? I know the solution for chart (Some information is here: [C# created Excel graph - Should be ScatterLine but it is Line type on other computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644273/c-sharp-created-excel-graph-should-be-scatterline-but-it-is-line-type-on-other)), but the chart can't even be created!

Now I just suggest to do checking before the main chart making procedure.

```
            try
            {
                Excel.Shape chart_tmp = xlMYSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                chart_tmp.Delete();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //throw;
                MessageBox.Show("You can’t create chart properly if you have previously set an MS Excel default chart belonging to one of the following chart groups: Stock charts and Surface charts. Please set any other MS Excel default chart type.",
                                "Change MS Excel default chart type", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                throw new Exception("MS Excel default chart type is need to be changed!");
```

UPDATE:
In the main code I use Excel.ChartObjects. And it gives an error with chart adding anyway.
It's why I do so simple checking.

```
    // No error
    Excel.Shape chart_tmp = xlSourceSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Excel.XlChartType.xlLine, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    chart_tmp.Delete();
    // Error in any case if wrong default charts had been set by user
    Excel.ChartObjects xlDestCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlSourceSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
    Excel.ChartObject MyChart = xlDestCharts.Add(0, 0, 100, 500);
```

Comment: The first parameter to `AddChart` is an `xlChartType` enum value.  Have you tried specifying a value there?

Comment: I have updated main question.